# Are global variables in XSLT contending for partially matching values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is the strangest XSLT situation I have run into lately, I am showing an excerpt here to illustrate the structure but it's not really feasible to create a stand alone demo.  This XSLT 1.0 transform runs under MSXML on Windows 2008 Server.  Here is the code, I cannot simplify the unfortunately convoluted structure any (don't ask why), but I am getting what appears to be a contention or confusion about global variable naming.

```
<xsl:variable name="GlobalY">501</xsl:variable>

<xsl:param name="YMax">     
    <xsl:variable name="YMax">
        <xsl:call-template name="CalculateArea"/>       
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$YMax"/>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template name="CalculateArea">
    <xsl:value-of select="$GlobalY"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    YMax = <xsl:value-of select="$YMax"/>
</xsl:template>
```

One would think that first global variable, `GlobalY` would be available throughout all the more local templates or declarations inside of them, even if there are several layers of indirection underneath.  What I am seeing though, is that when the letter `Y` appears in the initial declaration, the variable goes opaque (zero length, no content) but if I switch to variable name `Global` by itself, the reference works fine.  The data type involved is just plain text, no RTFs involved. There are a number of variables with the letter `Y` in them.

I am stumped.  I've trial-and-errored everyhing I can imagine.  Does MSXML suffer from overloading variable name space where it gets confused?  Thank you, XSLT fans!

Comment: I tried to convert your posted code into a minimal stylesheet by wrapping it into `xsl:stylesheet` and then run it using MSXML 3 and the output is `YMax = 501`. So which output do you get, which version of MSXML do you use? How do you use MSXML, using the command line tool msxsl, with your own code? You might need to provide more information to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPv also gives the right result it seems.

Comment: Hi Martin, Bluewood's clue below got me over the fault, it was related to xsl:includes occurring before, or after, setup of global variables.  It didn't seem obvious how a one-letter change in a variable name would break it, since there are no name conflicts throughout my code set.  I use the default MSXML version for Windows 2008 Server, but I don't have version number handy (Microsoft makes this rather confusing).  I create a transform processor in ASP, using, `CreateObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate")`  Unfortunately the vagaries of how my code is put together makes it hard to provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are using a global variable within a param.  The template CalculateArea uses your global variable, and CalculateArea is called from the param YMax.  This means that your global variable may not be instantiated before it is used.  If you have not already done so, put a break point on everything and step through the code in the debugger.  Ensure GlobalY is instantiated before YMax.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.  The code is instantiated in the order shown.  Also, what was wierd is, if you take the "Y" out of the variable name, it works.

Comment: The whole thing with it working using a different name got me thinking a bit.  So, here is a quote from page 431 of XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 4th addition.  "Also, remember that when one stylesheet module imports another, the importing module can override an <xsl:param> in the imported module with an <xsl:variable>, or vice versa.  Maybe that helps, if you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

Bluewood66 provided a clue leading to the answer.  I rearranged the order of global variables, `xsl:include`s, then templates.  Having the globals instantiated first, before include code brought in a lot of references to them was crucial.  Still, it seemed odd that a one-character change in a global variable name would break and unbreak the symptom. Seems like "all" globals would be broken not just one.  There were no conflicting names, in the entire code set.  THANKS, Bluewood!

Comment: Dave,  I find that sometimes I can use global parameters in my global variables and sometimes I cannot.  Because sometimes the global parameters get instantiated first and sometimes the global variables get instantiated first.  And, I have yet to figure why.  When I need a global parameter to be used to create a variable, I create the variable within a root node template and pass it as a parameter to all of the other templates.

Comment: Yep, been there done that, if you can't get the global without, you can also pass it thru.  Unfortunately my XSLT dev environment is Notepad, so there's nothing fancy like code tracing, break points, etc.  Pure trial and error.